# SQL query for object and child collection

Tags: sql, pivot

I need help to write correct SQL query for my DB tables.
Now I have two simple tables:

[image: my objects description]

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm almost sure it's impossible

Comment: Whats the database?Also I hope you didnt work too hard for your attempted query.

Comment: Database is MS SQL. Mihai, you SQL query is not valid - incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT mainobjectid,name,
MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNAme='ColumnName1' THEN ColumnContent ELSE 0 END)as ColumnName1,
MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNAme='ColumnName2' THEN ColumnContent ELSE 0 END)as ColumnName2,
MAX(CASE WHEN ColumnNAme='ColumnName3' THEN ColumnContent ELSE 0 END)as ColumnName3
FROM t1 JOIN t2
ON t1.mainobjectid=t2.mainobjectid
GROUP BY t1.mainobjectid
```

Should work on most popular databases.

Comment: Database is MS SQL. Mihai, you SQL query is not valid - incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

Comment: @Oblomingo Missing comma,try again.

Comment: Ok, now it's working. But I don't know ColumnName values, is it possible to get it dynamically?

Comment: @Oblomingo I think so,but unfortunately this is beyond my pay grade.